# Thymeleaf not able to display the value of Model object attribute

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am newbie to Spring boot and Thymeleaf. I have created a mock setup for learning Thymeleaf with Spring boot.

Here I am not able to see the value of the Model attribute in the index.html page.
I am unable to read the value of the Model attribute in html page.
Below is my code I written until now.

**HelloWorldSpringBoot.java**

```
package com.test.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldSpringBoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldSpringBoot.class, args);
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldController**

```
package com.test.app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String hello(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("test","value1");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
   <h1 th:text="${test}"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.template-loader-path: classpath:/static/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix: .html
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false
```

**Maven pm.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorldSpringBoot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Could any one help me in displaying the value in index.html page.

Comment: Just as a note, `static` specifically means *does not vary*; there's a good reason that templates go in `src/main/resources/templates` by default, and I strongly recommend you move your HTML file there and drop all configuration except the cache-disable.

Comment: In order to debug this, you'll need to include the HTML output, as seen in your browser's "View Source". (It _looks_ like a correct setup.)

Comment: @chrylis is correct.  You can also remove any resolver configuration if you have any, as it would not be needed for Spring Boot in this simple scenario.

Comment: @chrylis I dint have any resolver configurations.

Comment: @chrylis I tried replacing the index.html from static folder to templates. But I am unable to see the value of test from Model attribute. Any other changes from my code?

Comment: You still didn't post the output that you get.